# The first 2 Threads are not being executed if I create threads in a loop

Tags: c, multithreading, posix, posix-api

I am using MINGW in my Windows 7 machine for POSIX thread coding.

Consider the following simple code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <process.h>
#define NUM_THREADS 5

void *PrintHello(void *threadid)
{
    long tid;
        tid = (long)threadid;
    printf("Hello Dude...!!!\t I am thread no #%ld\n",tid);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
int main()
{
    pthread_t thread[NUM_THREADS];
    int rc;
    long t;
    for(t=0;t<NUM_THREADS;t++)
    {
        printf("Inside the Main Thread...\nSpawning Threads...\n");
        rc=pthread_create(&thread[t],NULL,PrintHello,(void*)t);
        if(rc)
        {
            printf("ERROR: Thread Spawning returned code %d\n",rc);
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Above program when executed in my system it is showing the following output:

```
Inside the Main Thread...
Spawning Threads...
Inside the Main Thread...
Spawning Threads...
Hello Dude...!!!         I am thread no #0
Inside the Main Thread...
Spawning Threads...
Hello Dude...!!!         I am thread no #1
Inside the Main Thread...
Spawning Threads...
Hello Dude...!!!         I am thread no #2
Inside the Main Thread...
Spawning Threads...
```

This program was supposed to spawn 5 threads. But it had created only 2 threads. The first 2 and last 2 line suggests that pthread_create() routine is about to be called. And since the "rc" variable is not "1" so there is no question any ERROR in thread creation, otherwise it would had hit the "if(rc)" part.

So where is the error ? Or it is something related to my windows machine.

Answer (score 1):

There is no error.

Your program is exiting before the other threads have had a chance to output anything, and exiting your program kills all its threads.

You'll need to `pthread_join` all your threads if you want them all to finish properly.

Comment: Please search for `pthread_join`, you'll find lots of info and examples of exactly how you're supposed to do this. Simply call `pthread_join` on each of the spawned threads in a second loop in your `main`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the real problem is that your program ends when your main ends.  You should `pthread_join` to them before returning from main.  The other threads just aren't getting a chance to run before main exits, taking the whole process space (and your un-run threads) with it.

```
for(t=0;t<NUM_THREADS;t++)
{
    printf("Inside the Main Thread...\nSpawning Threads...\n");
    rc=pthread_create(&thread[t],NULL,PrintHello,(void*)t);
    if(rc)
    {
        printf("ERROR: Thread Spawning returned code %d\n",rc);
        exit(-1);
    }
}

/* add this and you're golden! */
for(t=0; t<NUM_THREADS;t++) {
    pthread_join(thread[t], NULL);
}
```

Below was my original answer and still good advice:

don't pass a long as a void*.  Pass the address of it.  If you need to, make a copy of it each time through the loop to pass in and free it up later.

```
long thread_data[NUM_THREADS];
for(t=0;t<NUM_THREADS;t++)
    {
        thread_data[t] = t;
        printf("Inside the Main Thread...\nSpawning Threads...\n");
        rc=pthread_create(&thread[t],NULL,PrintHello,(void*)&(thread_data[t]));
        if(rc)
        {
            printf("ERROR: Thread Spawning returned code %d\n",rc);
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I had changed the long to int but still the first thread is not getting executed...